# How to create a dynamic help embed using discord.js so that commands are organized by category

Tags: discord.js

When making a Discord bot it's obviously really inefficient (and possibly inaccurate) to manually hard-code every command, description and category into a help embed, so I decided to make it automatic with the following code:

```
    const commands = loadCommands()
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    embed.setTitle('Commands List')
    embed.setColor(`${embedColor}`)
    embed.setDescription('Prefix: `' + `${prefix}`+ '` \n\n')
    let list = ' '
    for (const command of commands) {
   
      const mainCommand =
        typeof command.commands === 'string'
          ? command.commands
          : command.commands[0]
      const args = command.expectedArgs ? ` ${command.expectedArgs}` : ''
      const { description } = command

      list += ' `'+`${mainCommand}`+'` '
    }
    
    embed.addFields(
        {name: 'general commands', value: list, inline: true
        })
    message.channel.send(embed)
  },
}
```

and it takes all of my commands and places them into the embed.

The problem is that I don't know how to make it sort by category.  I already have categories listed for all commands (for example, commands like 'help' and 'ping' are in Utilities); I'd like to be able to make it so that the embed has one field for each category, with the value being all of the commands in a category.

On that note, I'd also like to know how to make it so that if you do a command like `<prefix>help [command]`, the bot checks to see if [command] exists, and if it does, the bot returns a harded-coded description for that command (if [command] does not exist, the bot will return the generic help embed).

Thanks in advance for any and all help provided.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you need something like this type of Embed:

```
const commandsEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0091ff')
    .setTitle('Commands Help!')
    .setDescription('Below you will see the available commands of our Bot!')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Utilities', value: '!help, !ping' },
        { name: 'Command Category 2', value: 'Commands' },
        { name: 'Command Category 3', value: 'Some other Commands' },
    )
    .setTimestamp()
```

For your second Question, i think the most Practical would be to copy and paste and make some seperate embeds (all the same colour, syntax etc as the original) and have them been sent when the user uses a command. For instance:

```
if(msg.content === `${prefix}help Utility`){
   msg.user.send(helpEmbed);
}
if (msg.content === `${prefix}help OtherCommands {
.
.
.
};
```